# css background image nto displaying in div

Tags: css, background-image

i'm trying to get my background image to display within the header div but it is not displaying. Can someone tell where on what i'm doing wrong?

css code:

```
#header{
width:900px;
/*background-color:#009999;*/
background-image:url('../images/background_img.jpg');
float:left;
text-align:center;
}
```

html code

```
<body>
<div class="contentwrapper">
<div id="header">
hello

<!--<div id="logo">
    <img src="images/small_gama_logo.png" />
</div>
<div id="company_name">
    <h1>Gama Corporate Services Sdn Bhd</h1>
</div>-->
</div>
<div id="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>About</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: yes, i even tried putting the image in the document root (where the html documents exists) instead of the image sub folder. Still no change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add height to your div.

If you remove it, it actually does still display, so you must really check your paths for the img, plus the name. Make sure it is all correct and that the img exists in the directory you intend.

```
#header{
width:900px;
/*background-color:#009999;*/
background-image:url('http://placehold.it/200x200');
float:left;
text-align:center;
height: 200px;
}​
```

I copy/pasted your code and added only height, changed the img location so your code is fine. Must be a problem with the img.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/qtenp/

Comment: Ok, it works now. Actually the image was corrupted. Thats why it wasn't displaying. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It is displaying fine in firefox, but it is not displaying in IE.

Comment: Which version of IE? Have you cleared the browser cache? (ctrl+F5)

Comment: Sorry, yesterday was a public holiday. I'm using IE9 and I have already cleared browser cache still background image is not displaying. Can you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a height for your DIV also. It does not get automatically sized based on your background image.

Comment: i tried setting the height for #header but still the image is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

set the height attribute for #header too

```
#header{
 width:900px;
 height: 400px;
 /*background-color:#009999;*/
 background-image:url('../images/background_img.jpg');
 float:left;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: `#header` has content (text 'hello') so it has some dimensions, no need to explicitly set height with CSS

Answer (score 0):

Hi now used **Height**

```
#header{
height:100px;
}
```

Comment: i tried setting min-height, it didn't work, then i tried setting height still the background image is not displaying.

Comment: @vaanipala can u post your image and your code in live or jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0):

Most probably URL to background image is incorrect (please note that it is relative to URL of CSS file).
Also `background-image` could be overridden by more specific CSS rules.

Also, it would be very helpful to see live example on http://jsfiddle.net